# Update multiple rows with multiple 'where' clauses using CASE

Tags: mysql, optimization, case

I have the following query and want to optimize it.  This could be up to 300 or more trips to the database.

```
update evtentries
  set ro = '1',
  ediv = 'A'
  where 
  entid = '1234' and ID = '10024'

update evtentries
  set ro = '2',
  ediv = 'B'
  where 
  entid = '5678' and ID = '10024'
```

I have found some information with using case, but not sure how to incorporate it with 2 field on each.

```
update evtentries
  set ro = CASE WHEN entid = '1234' THEN '1'
                WHEN entid = '5678' THEN '2'
                ELSE ro
                END
     , ediv = 'A'  <---- need to update with the case
WHERE entid IN ('1234', '5678') and ID = '10024'
```

How do I use case or add the ediv field part of this case query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the second column exactly like the first one.

```
update evtentries
set ro = CASE entid
        WHEN '1234' THEN '1'
        WHEN '5678' THEN '2'
        ELSE ro
    END,
    ediv = CASE entid
        WHEN '1234' THEN 'A'
        WHEN '5678' THEN 'B'
        ELSE ediv
    END
WHERE entid IN ('1234', '5678') and ID = '10024'
```

You don't really need the `ELSE` cases since the `WHERE` clause ensures that only the `WHEN` clauses will be matched, but there's no harm in keeping it for safety.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.  I didn't even think about using the  entid again.

Comment: Why would it be different?

Comment: @Barmar Sir Barmar, when you say `there's no harm in keeping it for safety` , is there a possibility the `ELSE` clause could ever happen with the current search condition?

Comment: No, there's no possibility. The safety is in case you forget to put `WHERE entid IN (...)`.